# At what level should i integrate two services (client vs server)

Tags: java, rest, integration, rmi, rpc

I have a service Stock/Products(REST API) and a service Orders (RPC API). The Orders service will use some data from Stock/Products.

Orders will be used from a GUI Client.

I see two options for integrating:

1. use Stock/Products from the Orders service itself (integrate in the server)
2. use Stock/Products from the GUI client.(integrate in the client/UI)

Which would be a better approach?
I tend to choose (2) because i don't see why I would 'tunnel' the REST API through the RPC API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should prefer integration in the server, because encapsulation is better that way.   Your chief objective should be to make life as easy for clients as possible.

The client should only need to know that they want their orders.  Let the server handle the details of assembling products.

You have a perfect example in Amazon.com.  They let you get what you need with a single request, but lots of services participate in making it so.